# VB.Net WebClient DownloadFile Won't Save to Variable Filename?

Tags: vb.net, webclient

Trying to download a website to a file using WebClient DownloadFile works fine as long as I have a preset filename for it. If the filename is variable it throws an exception and I can't work out why.

```
dim link as string = "http://google.com"
Dim myWebClient As New System.Net.WebClient
myWebClient.DownloadFile(link, link & ".html")
```

If the output is set to "site.html" it'll work just fine but I can't get it to accept a variable.

I'm passing the variable link to the sub and I want it to save that site to The-Sitename.html. I'm guessing there is something really simple I'm missing here?

Comment: You cannot use the URI string as the name of your file. Use a regular file name and the variable will work as expected

Comment: Literally just noticed that as I posted this you beat me to posting but I had time to kick myself. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You cant save a file with the website extension included in the URL

Try using the following code to exclude common extensions to hopefully fix the issue

```
link = link.Replace("http://", "")
link = link.Replace("https://", "")
myWebClient.DownloadFile(link, link & ".html")
```